# Why is integral $\int \cos (t-u)\, du = -\sin(t-u)$

Tags: integration

$$\int \cos(u)\,du= -\sin(u) + C $$

But why is,

$$\int \cos (t-u)\,du=\ -\sin(t-u)$$

and not $\sin(t-u)$?

Comment: as one of the comments says, to verify that the integral is correct, all you have to do is find $\frac{d}{dt}(-\sin(t-u))$.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're only confusion stems from the fact that you're incorrect at the start: $$\int \cos u = \sin u + C$$

Recall that $\dfrac d{dx}(\sin x + C) = \cos x \implies \int \cos x = \sin x + C$

---

So it would follow, by the chain rule, letting $w = t-u \implies \,dw = \,-du \iff \color{blue}{\bf-dw = du},\;$ that $$\int \cos(t - u) \,\color{blue}{\bf du} = \int \cos w\color{blue}{\bf(-dw)} \;\;= \;-\;\int \cos w\,dw\; = \;- \sin(w) + C = -\sin(t-u) +C$$

---

The nice thing about integrals is that you can always check your work by taking the derivatives of the result to see if you obtain the original integrand!

Comment: +1 for your last comment.  I would have answered the whole question that way.

Comment: Could the downvoter please offer a reason for the downvote?

Comment: @amWhy, same problem here:). I'm also another victim

Answer (score 2):

Because $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d(-\sin(t-u))}{\mathrm du}=-\frac{\mathrm d\left(\sin(t-u)\right)}{\mathrm du}=-\frac{\mathrm d(t-u)}{\mathrm du}\cdot\sin'(t-u)=+\cos(t-u).$

Answer (score 0):

Putting $\displaystyle t-u=v\implies -du=dv$

$$\int\cos(t-u)du=-\int \cos vdv=-\sin v=\cdots$$

Comment: @Downvoter, have you noticed the edited Question? May I request you to pinpoint the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of integrals can also be easily done by inspection.

We want to find a functions whose derivative is $\cos(t-u)$. A good first guess is $\sin(t-u)$. But differentiating it gives $-\cos(t-u)$. To solve that problem, put a negative sign upfront, and you've found your indefinite integral: $-\sin(t-u) + C$ for an arbitrary $C$.